# Additional job not in contract

Tags: salary, new-job, contracts, raise

I've been working for a few months now in my new work and originally I signed to be an iOS Developer. During the interview however I stated that I can do web development so that is something that I need to do from time to time as it is my employers services is to provide Facebook apps for their client. When I came in, the company was outsourcing the Android app and website of our biggest project to another country while I take over the iOS version of the app. After a month my employer got impressed with me and decided to stop outsourcing and asked me to take over the Android app. I declined for the reason that I wanted to make sure I can focus on the iOS app and not under deliver because I am not that good with Android development. But my employer insisted and so I had to say yes. After a few months I started to take over another project this time a web site.

My question is, would it be reasonable to ask for a salary raise after my probation? If I for example earn $100 for being an iOS dev. Would it be reasonable to ask for $50 more if I do web development and Android development? The point is I am now doing new responsibilities on top of being an iOS developer.

Comment: Are you actually doing twice as much work, i.e. working twice as many hours?

Comment: Not really twice as many hours. But I am working more than my official 8 hrs a day though my employer doesnt require me to work extra hours. Its because we make a timeline of tasks for both iOS and Android development and now I have to add the Android development on my timeline.

Comment: it is always reasonable to ask for a salary raise. they're not going to fire you for asking for one. you might want to make an argument about doing more work, or more valuable work tho.

Comment: I think 50% rise would be turned down got for 10-15% unless your relay low paid then just leave. And I bet your contract says "and other duties"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news: an iOS/Android job description would ordinarily command a higher salary than either iOS or Android (because it is somewhat harder to find a single person who can do both well than one person who can do just one well, where it requires proficiency in two sets of languages and APIs).

The bad news is that the right time to negotiate was when your boss asked you to do something that was some way outside of your job description. Unfortunately the status quo is now that you are an Android/iOS developer paid the rate an iOS developer would be.

> But my employer insisted and so I had to say yes.

Nope. You could have said no. You were hired as an iOS dev and agreed to become an iOS/Android dev at no extra charge: this will make it more difficult.

By all means go into your negotiation meeting asking for and expecting an increase, but be prepared for your boss to drive a hard as they won't be expecting to pay you more. Think about the responses you're likely to get. Be prepared also to look at your other options if you decide your pay is not commensurate with your work.

How much is that? We can't answer that for you: look at other jobs past and present for both. It depends on either your local employment market. In general having a second, distinct skill will probably not result in an adjustment less than 5% and probably not more than 50%. However, you mention promotion so factor in whatever you'd negotiate for ordinary progression and inflation-related increase as well.

The one argument not to make is over time. Either you're paid hourly, in which case the more time you work the more money you get, or you're not in which case if Android work takes time away from iOS development the employer accepts a greater risk of missed deadlines or bugs. Yes, it might be harder on you but you're not paid to slack.

Comment: I did say no that time but i didnt have a choice when my manager insisted. I was a month in into the job at that time. They were outsourcing all their projects before i got in and at that time they just realized how good it is to have a full time dev. Ill take your advice of researching the market for ios and android dev and maybe ask for that range upon negitiation.

Comment: You always have the opportunity to say no. It's difficult to get the courage to do this when new in role, and some managers play on this.